# UiObject clickAndWaitForNewWindow takes too long to load

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

In our uiautomator test cases we use UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow to trigger any clicking action. However sometimes it just simply takes too long for device to response / load the page. Thus before the page is completely loaded any follow-up analysis / test fails as the expected widgets are not ready yet. This fails some of our test cases in an undetermined way. Most of time simply rerunning the test cases they pass.

Is there any way to make sure UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow loads the expected page completely before continuing on next verification? We can insert a sleep statement right after UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow, which works as double-edge sword, but that does not really solve this problem.

```
UiObject.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
// how to wait until the page is loaded completely
new UiSelector(...); // search for widgets that are supposed to be on the newly loaded page
```

Answer (score 0):

One way here can be to add a while loop here.

Say when you tap on some element in one window and then a new screen appears and you want to perform action on some element (say menu) in the new window and that element is defined as -

```
//say you tapped on some element(say abc) on the first window
abc.click();

//now you want to wait till the element (say menu) appears on the next screen which is decl as -
UiObject menu =  new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.test:id/elmnt"));

//add a while loop to check if that element exists and add a print statement just to keep printing till that element appears on the screen-
while (!menu.exists()) {

    System.out.println("Menu will appear in some time");

}

System.out.println("Menu appeared");
//carry other operations here
```

Comment: thanks Smriti!

this assumes we know the resource-id "com.example.test:id/elmnt". what if we don't? or even worse we don't know any special widget that can help us identify the new page.

Comment: maybe I should ask this way, is there anyway, like ctor constructing a complete object before returning, in ui automator that tells all widgets are ready on the new page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
UiDevice.waitForWindowUpdate(package, timeout);
```

and it's working fine so far. With this you don't need the id of any element. I think there's also the option of not having timeout.